# What is more efficient - concatenating small strings or substring of a longer string

Tags: c++, string, performance, string-concatenation

I have a use case in which I receive data coming in as chunks in the form of delimited strings. This is a one time operation.

Later I need to use that data at many places, which require different representations of the data based on user input. At some places I need it as a single string including all the delimiters and at some other places I need individual smaller strings.

Note: The number of input strings has a fixed upper bound, i.e. they can never be more than 10.

For example,

```
    Incoming data:
        this is string 1- this is string 2- this is string 3

    Expected output (1):
        this is string 1-this is string 2-this is string 3

    Expected output (2):
        this is string 1-
        this is string 2-
        this is string 3
```

I have a couple of design ideas that I am not sure which one is more efficient. I want to know which approach is more efficient, keeping in mind that object will be created once but may be accessed several times during its life time.

1.

```
    class Msg1
    {
    private:
        std::vector<std::string> strings;

    public:
        std::string getString() {
            // returns strings concatenated in one long string
        }

        std::string getString(int index) {
            // returns strings[index]
        }

    };
```

2. 

```
    class Msg2
    {
    private:
        std::string string1;
        std::string string2;
        std::string string3;
        // ...

        public: std::string getString() {
            // returns string1 + string2 + string3
        }

        std::string getString(int index) {
            // switch(index) {
                // case 1:
                // return string1;
                // break;
                // ...
            // }
        }
    };
```

3. 

```
    class Msg3
    {
    private:
        std::string longString

        public: std::string getString() {
            // returns longString
        }

        std::string getString(int index) {
            // find index location of '-'
            // substring until next location '-' or end of string
            // return this substring
        }
    };
```

Comment: There rarely is any universal answer to 'Which is more efficient ...?' questions. If you want to know then try both methods and measure whatever it is that you are interested in. If this process doesn't give any significant difference then the correct choice is to write the simplest code not the most efficient code.

Comment: The strings aren't very long, unless your code is particularly performance critical just write the code in the simplest most understandable way

Comment: I notice that all your proposals have the same API, which is good. So given that I would just postpone this decision, pick the easiest option, finish the rest of your code. Then at the end if you do have some performance issues revisit this choice. Programming is an iterative process, code can be rewritten.

Comment: Did you **try it for your specific use case**?

Comment: The only answer on such questions: Measure under real conditions. Every compiler, CPU or OS may give very different results. As such, you must measure to get a real answer. All use cases I saw in my live were not depending on such decisions. Mostly some major design bug has killed the performance... but that is another topic..

Comment: Do you really need `std::string`? Is long string and multiple `std::string_view` an option?

Answer (score 2):

There are no advantages to variant #2 (storing multiple individual `std::string` objects as class members) over variant #1 (storing multiple `std::string` objects in a single `std::vector`). Variant #2 also has severe disadvantages in that it is more difficult to maintain and expand compared to variant #1.

Therefore, we need only compare variant #1 (storing the individual strings separately and concatenating them on-demand) to variant #3 (storing the concatenated string and extracting substrings on-demand). Which one is more efficient is going to depend on the actual use-case.

Insertion of new substrings should be equally efficient in both variants #1 and #3. Variant #1 using the vector may have a *slight* advantage, but all of your performance gains with respect to insertion of substrings will come from pre-allocating sufficient space (either in the `std::vector` or in the monolithic `std::string`) to store all of the substrings that you expect to need to store in order to avoid re-allocations as you add additional substrings.

Aside from insertion, variant #1 optimizes for fast look-up (return) of individual substrings, while penalizing retrieving the concentrated string (because it has to build it on-demand). Variant #3 optimizes in precisely the opposite way: it maintains the concatenated string, so it can be quickly retrieved, but if you want to retrieve substrings, that will be slower, because it has to iterate through and find them via tokenization.

Choosing between variants #1 and #3 is thus a relatively straightforward matter of deciding whether you need fast retrieval of individual substrings or fast retrieval of the concatenated string.

Of course, you could build a hybrid implementation. For example, if you expected to need to retrieve the concatenated string multiple times, then instead of building it each time on demand, you could modify variant #1 to generate the concatenated string once and cache it. Subsequent retrievals would then return this pre-computed cached string, which would be extremely fast. Alternatively, you could modify variant #3 to maintain a list of indices corresponding to the starting offset of each substrings, allowing you to look up each of them extremely quickly.

Note that your pseudo-code implementation is making multiple copies of strings. If you don't need copies, return constant references to the cached member variables. If possible, also consider using a `std::string_view` (C++17 and later) instead of a `std::string` so you don't need to copy the string data into the class at all.

Answer (score 1):

If the strings are read-only, use `std::string_view`. The code could either store the offset and length of each string, or just store the `string_view` instance directly.

```cpp
class Msg
{
private:
    std::string long_string;
    // > Note: The number of input strings has a fixed upper bound, i.e. they can never be more than 10.
    std::array<std::string_view, 10> each_string;

public:
    [[nodiscard]] auto get_string(std::size_t index) const -> std::string_view
    {
        return each_string[index];
    }
};
```

Comment: Please don't use inline code formatting for jargon (technical terms) - it is only for actual code that is relevant to the problem (for example, names of classes used in the code, like `string_view`), not for concepts involved in understanding the code (like "read-only"). I have fixed this, and also attempted to improve the wording to make it clearer and more professional.

Comment: Do you really like the syntax "auto Foo() -> type' for normal functions? I do not :-)